# Using Silenium with webdriver for Chrome and getting "Permission denied" or "No such file or directory" (Mac)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Python with selenium to automate downloading files from a website, but when I try to call chromeDriver I get an error. I've tried two different ways but without success. Any ideas on how I can fix one way or the other to work?

**Way 1:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages')
```

This produces the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/katejohnston/Desktop/Monday Workflow.py", line 17, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 86, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'site-packages' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

**Way 2**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/Chrome/chromedriver.exe')
```

This produces the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Chrome/chromedriver.exe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/katejohnston/Desktop/Monday Workflow.py", line 18, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/Chrome/chromedriver.exe')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: Probably is just about permission https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/permission-open-a-file-folder-mac-mchlp1038/mac

Comment: I moved it to the desktop and set all permissions to Read & Write but it still didn't work, so I deleted and manually re-installed it (previously I used the Command Terminal to install), then re-started the computer, and now it works!

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem when I tried running the driver on a linux server.
Using

```
chmod +x chromedriver
```

did the trick for me.
(Thx to [@Thomas Q](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10339008/thomas-q) for his comment with this tip!)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the appropriate chromedriver for your system. In your case you will download chromedriver_mac64.zip. You can get it [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads). Then you need to extract the the chromedriver file from the zip and place it in the same directory as the python script and use the relative path

`from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver')`

You can also use the absolute path to the file if you want. It would look something like this is if you were to drag the file to your desktop:

`from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/YOUR_USERNAME/Desktop/chromedriver')`

Comment: And what about the version?

Comment: Get whichever version of chromedriver that you want. The later the better, usually

Comment: you can also place it anywhere on system PATH and not specify the location.

Comment: get the version that matches your Chrome version.

Comment: you also need to set permissions to make it executable (`chmod +x chromedriver`)

Comment: There is no need to `chmod +x chromedriver` as the extracted file already has the permissions. Either way I don't think it should matter if it is executable or not

Comment: I moved it to the desktop and set all permissions to Read & Write but it still didn't work, so I deleted and manually re-installed it (previously I used the Command Terminal to install), then re-started the computer, and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:` and like Corey, when I deleted any copy of `Chromedriver` I then downloaded and unzipped the file and placed it in my user directory, it just worked.